# R Shiny: Is it possible to build Shiny app where user can choose SQL:s "where condition" variables and export the query results

Tags: r, shiny

How can I do the following in Shiny (or is it possible).
Id like to have an UI where user can choose what he wants to pass to SQL:s "where-condition". Then user could click "Run"-button and the results of the query are exported to his folder.

For example, I have a sql clause: 
select * from Animaldata where animal_type in ('Cat')

Now Id like to have an UI where user can just select what to put into the "where-condition". So he sees options "Dog", "Cat" and can select the ones he wants. for example, user selects only "Dog" and clicks "Run", then we export automatically the query results to some specified folder.

Comment: See these series of articles https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/overview.html or you can directly see this https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very possible (I've done this in many apps).  Your question is hard to answer, as it's not a specific coding question.  Also you've not indicated which database application you're using, so its hard to advise on anything related to the R drivers.  Generally, use a DBI compliant driver and strongly recommend to pass user-input as a parameter list (to protect sql-injection attacks).

```
library(your DBI compliant package)

selections <- input$my_selections #input from shiny
selections <- as.vector(selections) #here may encounter driver/database compliance issues as you may or may not be able to pass-in a vector/array object.  If not you can pass-in a string and split it on the database end
selections <- paste0(as.vector(selections),collapse=",") #alternative input

conn <- #your connection to the database
result <- dbGetQuery(conn,"select * from Animaldata where animal_type in ( $1 )",
                     params=list(selections))
```